I've created an overview page and I want to connect a custom filter with a custom card
I created an overview page in VS Code using the EntitySet and Entity generated in SAP (TCODE: SEGW).
I added a custom card and a custom filter, but they are not connected to each other.
Is there any solution for this?
I want the data to appear as a chart in the SmartChart inside the custom card when I enter a date in the Grdat field of the custom filter.
I have defined the custom filter and card in the manifest.json, but I'm not sure how to define the custom filter as a globalFilter so that it connects with the card.

manifest.json

{
    "_version": "1.42.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "customcard1",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "0.0.1"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "resources": "resources.json",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "@sap/generator-fiori:ovp",
            "version": "1.14.5",
            "toolsId": "1dd21f17-4ef1-4c94-a1c0-719a2444b4ee"
        },
        "dataSources": {
            "mainService": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/service/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "annotations": [
                        "annotation"
                    ],
                    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml",
                    "odataVersion": "2.0"
                }
            },
            "annotation": {
                "type": "ODataAnnotation",
                "uri": "annotations/annotation.xml",
                "settings": {
                    "localUri": "annotations/annotation.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "flexEnabled": true,
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.102.2",
            "libs": {
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.ushell": {},
                "sap.f": {},
                "sap.ui.comp": {},
                "sap.ui.generic.app": {},
                "sap.suite.ui.generic.template": {},
                "sap.ovp": {},
                "sap.ui.rta": {},
                "sap.ui.layout": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "customcard1.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "mainModel": {
                "dataSource": "mainService",
                "preload": true,
                "settings": {
                    "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Inline",
                    "refreshAfterChange": false,
                    "metadataUrlParams": {
                        "sap-value-list": "none"
                    }
                }
            },
            "@i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "uri": "i18n/i18n.properties"
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": []
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {},
            "routes": [],
            "targets": {}
        },
        "extends": {
            "extensions": {
                "sap.ui.controllerExtensions": {
                    "sap.ovp.app.Main": {
                        "controllerName": "customcard1.ext.controller.OverViewPageExt"
                    }
                },
                "sap.ui.viewExtensions": {
                    "sap.ovp.app.Main": {
                        "SmartFilterBarControlConfigurationExtension|ZSCFMPEBAPST": {
                            "className": "sap.ui.core.Fragment",
                            "fragmentName": "customcard1.ext.fragments.filterBar",
                            "type": "XML"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ovp": {
        "globalFilterModel": "mainModel",
        "globalFilterEntityType": "ZSCFMPEBAPST",
        "containerLayout": "resizable",
        "enableLiveFilter": true,
        "considerAnalyticalParameters": false,
        "cards": {
            "cardId": {
                "template": "customcard1.ext.customCardFolder",
                "settings": {
                    "title": "CustomCard",
                    "entitySet": "PEBAPSTSet",
                    "addODataSelect": true
                    
                }
            }
        },
        "chartSettings": {}
    },
    "sap.fiori": {
        "registrationIds": [],
        "archeType": "analytical"
    }
}

Finally, this is the annotation... I've wasted two days on this and still haven't found a solution.
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/Common.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1" Alias="Common"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/UI.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1" Alias="UI"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/Communication.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Communication.v1" Alias="Communication"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="/sap/opu/odata/sap/service/$metadata">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="service"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="local">
            <Annotations Target="service.ZSCFMPEBAPST">
                <Annotation Term="UI.Chart">
                    <Record>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ChartType" EnumMember="UI.ChartType/Column"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Measures">
                    <Collection>
                        <PropertyPath>BookPosAmt</PropertyPath>
                        <PropertyPath>PositionCurr</PropertyPath>
                    </Collection>
                    </PropertyValue>
                    <PropertyValue Property="Dimensions">
                    <Collection>
                        <PropertyPath>Grdat</PropertyPath>
                    </Collection>
                    </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                 </Annotation> 
            </Annotations>  
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>

These are the controllers for each custom filter and custom card.

custom filter controller

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
     "customCardFolder/customCardName"
], function (Filter, customCardName) {
    "use strict";
    // controller for custom filter, navigation param, action(quick view and global filter), navigation target 
    // controller class name can be like app.ovp.ext.CustomFilter where app.ovp can be replaced with your application namespace
    return {

        onInit: function() {
            console.log("onInit triggered");

        },

        getCustomFilters: function () {
            /* This method returns a filter object to the OVP library. If there are multiple filters, they should 
            be clubbed into single Filter object. */
            console.log("getCustomFilters triggered");
        
            var oValue1 = this.oView.byId("Grdat").getValue();
            console.log("oValue1",oValue1 );

            var aFilters = [], oFilter1;
            if (oValue1) {
                oFilter1 = new Filter({
                    path: "Grdat",
                    operator: "EQ",
                    value1: oValue1
                });
                aFilters.push(oFilter1);
            }
            if (aFilters && aFilters.length > 0) {
                return (new Filter(aFilters, true));
            }
        },

        getCustomAppStateDataExtension: function (oCustomData) {
            //the content of the custom field will be stored in the app state, so that it can be restored later, for example after a back navigation.
            //The developer has to ensure that the content of the field is stored in the object that is returned by this method.
            console.log("getCustomAppStateDataExtension triggered");

            if (oCustomData) {
                var oCustomField1 = this.oView.byId("Grdat");
                if (oCustomField1) {
                    oCustomData.filterProperty = oCustomField1.getValue();
                }
            }
        },

        restoreCustomAppStateDataExtension: function (oCustomData) {
            //in order to restore the content of the custom field in the filter bar, for example after a back navigation,
            //an object with the content is handed over to this method. Now the developer has to ensure that the content of the custom filter is set to the control
            console.log("restoreCustomAppStateDataExtension triggered");

            if (oCustomData) {
                if (oCustomData.filterProperty) {
                    var oCustomField1 = this.oView.byId("Grdat");
                    oCustomField1.setValue(oCustomData.filterProperty);
                }
            }
        },
    }
});

2. custom card controller
(function () {
    "use strict";

    /* controller for custom card  */
    // Controller : https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/121b8e6337d147af9819129e428f1f75
    // controller class name can be like app.ovp.ext.customList.CustomList where app.ovp can be replaced with your application namespace
    sap.ui.define([
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
        "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
        "sap/ui/model/Filter",
        "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"
    ], function(Controller, Fragment, Filter, FilterOperator) {
        return {

            onInit: function () {

                console.log("card oninit triggered");

                var smartFilter = this.getView().byId("smartFilterbar");

                this.GloabalEventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
                this.GloabalEventBus.subscribe("Globalfilter", "GlobalFilterSeacrhfired", this.onfilterApply);
                this.onGlobalfilterApply.bind(this);

                var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("mainModel");
                this.getView().setModel(oModel, "mainModel");

            },

            onBeforeRebindChart: function (oEvent){
                console.log("onBeforeRebindChart triggered");
    
                var oDateValue = this.byId("Grdat").getValue(); 
                var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");  
    
                if (oDateValue) {   
                    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Grdat", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oDateValue); 
                    oBindingParams.filters.push(oFilter);
                }   
    
            },
    
            onAfterRendering: function () {
                console.log("onAfterRendering triggered");

                var oCardPropertiesModel = oView.getModel("mainModel");
                console.log("oCardPropertiesModel",oCardPropertiesModel);
                var sEntitySet = "/PEBAPSTSet";
                var oParamater = {
                    urlParameters: {
                        "$select": this.selectFields
                    },
                    filters: this.aFilter,
                    success: this._onSuccess.bind(this)
                };
                oModel.read(sEntitySet, oParamater);

            },

            onExit: function () {
                this.oMainModel.destroy();  
                this.oMainModel = null; 
            }
        }
    });
})();

